# Is there such thing as File name or handle to write to console?

Tags: python

I am using `myFile.write("...")` often and sometimes I'd like to see the output in the console rather than re-opening the updated file. I am using IDLE.

So, I'd like to know, instead of going and replacing `myFile.write()` with `print()` everywhere, can I replace the filename (`output.txt`) with something like STDIO when setting the myFile variable?

```
myFile = open("output.txt", "w")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `sys` module...

```
import sys
myFile=sys.stdout
myFile.write("Hello!\n")
```

`sys.stderr` is also available.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks for the snippet too :) Will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [sys.stdout](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout). Just use it like any other file handle. E.g.

```
print >> sys.stderr, "Hi! I'm an error!"
```

Comment: Or on python 3... `print ("Hi! I'm an error!",file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: @mgilson: True, however 2.x is still prevalent in production environments. Actually I'm not overly fond of either syntax, but if forced to choose I would rather have the file being written to specified first. Tomato / tomahto.

Comment: You can't write to `stdin`. Fixed that for you. ;)

Comment: @Li-aungYip: Did I really do that? Sheesh! Total brain fade. Thanks for catching/fixing it.